# Revolution Slider on diffrent screen resolution

Tags: wordpress, screen, revolution-slider

I have created a slider in my web site using Revolution Slider WordPress Plugin ,it seems good on my screen but when i use another screen (bigger) , my slide lose the  resolution and it look very bad 
My slider settings are : Auto responsive , Unlimited height is off , force full width is off , min height : 350 , Grid width : 960 , Grid height : 450 
My slide size 1920px *754 px
NB : I chnaged the slide resolution to 1150*450 but the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

Contact the plugin author at http://themepunch.com/support-center sending the link to your page directly.